# Using pagination is there a way to get facebook messages via graph api v6.0?

Tags: facebook, rest, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

Is there a way to get facebook messages via graph api v6.0? I am not able to use "since", "until" pagination on "conversations" endpoint.

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/conversations?since=<unix_timestamp>&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]&debug=all
```

I am not able to use "thread_id" end point since its deprecated in newer version of graph api.

Comment: getting messages of users is not possible anyway, you can only get messages of pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `since` and `until`, it seems like not all endpoints of Facebook Graph API can be used with time-based pagination. And the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/conversation) says that:

> The Conversations edge is not a Time-Based edge.

The idea is to use cursor-based pagination, and it works for conversations, the idea of this kind of pagination described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/

Comment: Got it. Used cursor based pagination it worked. Thanks.